# Should this question be migrated to here?

Tags: discussion

do you think that [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410860/duplicated-wordpress-site-isnt-available-in-an-nginx-environment) should be migrated to here from Unix&Linux?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a test / dev environment, then no.